# Can't run database query

Tags: mysql, wpdb

I am writing a function to query some information from a custom table in the database. It seems that I am unable to query the database on the field I need.

```
function ch_details_from_id($id) {

    global $wpdb;

    $details = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "ch_guests WHERE key = '" . $id . "'", ARRAY_A);

    return $details;
}
```

$id is currently '001'. If I search on any other field in the table, I get the expected results, but on this field nothing is returned.

If I run exactly the same query in phpMyAdmin, it works fine.

Comment: try running `"SELECT * FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "ch_guests WHERE key = '" . $id . "'"` query in your phpmyadmin, if possible, that will give you clear idea about the problem.

Comment: Yeah, it works fine in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: how you did it, by using echo $details ??

Comment: and enable the debug that will give you clear message about error.

Comment: I'm just var_dumping the details.

Comment: Just found the following in the php logs: `[10-May-2016 12:30:55 UTC] WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key = '001'' at line 1 for query SELECT * FROM wp_ch_guests WHERE key = '001'`

Comment: try running `"SELECT * FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "ch_guests WHERE key = " . $id `

Comment: or you can run `"SELECT * FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "ch_guests WHERE key=$id"`

Comment: Same issue with both…

Comment: I tested in my phpmyadmin, it is working, can you post the result of echo $details; here ?

Comment: working fine for me in phpmyadmin, but running through wordpress gives me `array(0) { } ` and the message `WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key = '001'' at line 1]
SELECT * FROM wp_ch_guests WHERE key = '001'`

Comment: Think I might have found my issue. "The column name 'key' is a MySQL reserved keyword." has appeared when I browse the structure.

Comment: try this SELECT * FROM wp_ch_guests WHERE key=001, I have only removed the space around equal and quotation from 001 .

Comment: You are correct, I should have noticed it before, use id or something .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here issue with the column name. You are using column **key** in the query which is the default keyword/index in mysql.

For resolving this kind of issue just use the "Grave accent(`)' symbol in the query for the column name, No need to change the column name. So in your case the right query is

```
$details = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "ch_guests WHERE `key` = '" . $id . "'", ARRAY_A);
```

Run the above query, This is working for me, so i believe will work for you as well.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `$wpdb->prepare` for queries, as it does all the sanitizing and escaping for you. Also, `key` is reserved as a field name in MySQL:

```
function ch_details_from_id($id) {

    global $wpdb;
    // or try using " . $wpdb->prefix . "ch_guests
    $query = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->ch_guests WHERE guest = %d";
    $details = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( $query, $id ) );

    return $details;

}
```

To debug, you can output the last query `$wpdb` has done.

Comment: Do not you think "key" is reserved word and we should use something else ??

Comment: Thanks, the issue was the choice of field name, but I have used `details = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "ch_guests WHERE guest = %s", $id ), ARRAY_A);` now.

Comment: Yes, that is definitely the issue as I had already tried `$wpd->prepare` before.

Answer (score -1):

The field name is a reserved name. Changing from `key` to `id` has solved the issue.